# How to make regex works with perl command and extract numbers from a file?

Tags: perl, sed, grep

I'm trying to extract from a tab delimited file a number that i need to store in a variable. I'm approaching the problem with a regex that thanks to some research online I have been able to built.

The file is composed as follow:

```
0   0   2500    5000
1   5000    7500    10000
2   10000   12500   15000
3   15000   17500   20000
4   20000   22500   25000
5   25000   27500   30000
```

I need to extract the number in the second column given a number of the first one. I wrote and tested online the regex:

```
(?<=5\t).*?(?=\t)
```

I need the 25000 from the sixth line.

I started working with *sed* but as you already know, it doesn't like lookbehind and lookahead pattern even with the `-E` option to enable extended version of regular expressions. I tried also with *awk* and *grep* and failed for similar reasons.

Going further I found that *perl* could be the right command but I'm not able to make it work properly. I'm trying with the command

```
perl -pe '/(?<=5\t).*?(?=\t)/' | INFO.out
```

but I admit my poor knowledge and I'm a bit lost.

The next step would be to read the "5" in the regex from a variable so if you already know problems that could rise, please let me know.

Comment: I bet you just need `n=5; awk -v n="$n" '$1 == n{print $2}' file.txt > INFO.out`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/e0w5vc).

Comment: What you have there is a `perl` boolean expression and no action (and no grouping), here is one way to do it: `perl -nE '/(?<=5\t)(.*?)(?=\t)/ && say $1'`

Comment: Btw. if your `grep` supports the `-P` flag you can do: `grep -Po '(?<=5\t).*?(?=\t)'`

Comment: Why is this closed?!  How can it be "more focused??"  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 5):

No need for lookbehinds -- split each line on space and check whether the first field is `5`.

In Perl there is a command-line option convenient for this, `-a`, with which each line gets split for us and we get `@F` array with fields

```
perl -lanE'say $F[1] if $F[0] == 5' data.txt
```

Note that this tests for `5` numerically (`==`)

Answer (score 3):

`grep` supports `-P` for perl regex, and `-o` for only-matching, so this works with a lookbehind:

```
grep -Po '(?<=5\t)\d+' file
```

That can use a shell variable pretty easily:

```
VAR=5 && grep -Po "(?<=$VAR\t)\d+"
```

Or `perl -n`, to show using `s///e` to match and print capture group:

```
perl -lne 's/^5\t(\d+)/print $1/e' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to use a regex? If all you are doing is finding lines starting with a 5 and getting the second column you could use `sed` and `cut`, e.g.:

```
<infile sed -n '/^5\t/p' | cut -f2
```

Output:

```
25000
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use sed, match 5 at the start of the string and after the tab capture the digits in a group

```
sed -En 's/^5\t([[:digit:]]+)\t.*/\1/p' file > INFO.out
```

The file INFO.out contains:

```
25000
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ var1=$(sed -n 's/^5[^0-9]*\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' input_file)
$ echo "$var1"
25000
```